# Typescript: TS2322 with Generics classes

Tags: typescript

Typescript gives me a hard time with generics. When compiling this project, I get a TS2322 error at `return new TransformedBase();` (you can c/c this project in the Typescript playground, it works)

For more context, we have a lot of project using a Core project. The goal is to mutualize all we can into Core, and use Angular injection to change the behaviour in each app.

Since `TB extends TransformedBase`, and I'm returning a `new TransformedBase()` why is Typescript refusing to compile?

Thank you

```
// Projet 'Core'
class Base {
    a: string;
}

class TransformedBase {
    z: string;
}

class BaseTransformer<B extends Base, TB extends TransformedBase> {
    transform(source: B): TB {
        return new TransformedBase();
    }
}

class GenericService<B extends Base, TB extends TransformedBase> {
    private transformer: BaseTransformer<B, TB>;
    constructor(transformer: BaseTransformer<B, TB>) {
        // transformer is injected
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }

    doWork(source: B): TB {
        return this.transformer.transform(source)
    }
}


// One of the project which use Core
// import Base from 'core/Base'
// import TransformedBase from 'core/TransformedBase'
// import BaseClass from 'core/BaseClass'

class Better extends Base {
    b: string;
}

class TransformedBetter extends TransformedBase {
    w: string;

    constructor(transformedBase: TransformedBase) {
        super();
        // Do something
        this.w = `Hello ${transformedBase.z}`;
    }
}

class BetterTransformer extends BaseTransformer<Better, TransformedBetter> {
    transform(source: Better): TransformedBetter {
        super.transform(source);
        return new TransformedBetter(super.transform(source));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you know is that `TB extends TransformedBase` then `TB` is a *subtype* of `TransformedBase`.  So every `TB` is a `TransformedBase`, but not every `TransformedBase` is necessarily a `TB`. So the implementation of `transform()` in `BaseTransformer` is incorrect. You'd need to return a new instance of `TB` but you don't have any constructor for it.

I'd suggest not even having an implementation for `BaseTransformer`, since it's pretty useless.  Maybe `BaseTransformer` should be an abstract class or interface instead.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: My example was pretty simple, in the real code, Base & TransformedBase contains real informations, so BaseTransformer does a real work, and BetterTransformer have to transform the datas from Better, but not the datas from Base.



Thanks for your help about `not every TransformedBase is necessarily a TB`, I didn't think of that, but it's pretty logical.